# How does __proto__ differ from constructor.prototype?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype-programming

```
function Gadget(name, color)
{
   this.name = name;
   this.color = color;
}

Gadget.prototype.rating = 3

var newtoy = new Gadget("webcam", "black")

newtoy.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype
```

It always returns the object with rating = 3.

But if I do the following:

```
newtoy.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__
```

The chain ends up returning `null`.

Also in Internet Explorer how would I check the null if there is not a `__proto__` property?

Comment: This [graph diagram](http://i.imgur.com/IkxPv.png) will help you understand the difference between prototype and __proto__.
You can follow the __proto__ chain from newtoy object, and then you will realize why the 3rd __Proto__ from newtoy is null.

Comment: Also its clear from the diagram that `newtoy.prototype` is not equal to `newtoy.constructor.prototype` and therefore `newtoy.constructor.prototype` will not have property called `rating`. Similarly `newtoy.constructor.prototype.constructor.property` will also not have property called `rating`.

Comment: Typo in last comment: therefore `newtoy.constructor.prototype` will have property called rating. Similarly `newtoy.constructor.prototype.constructor.property` will also have property called rating.

Comment: See also: [`__proto__` Vs. `prototype` in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9959727/1048572) and [How does JavaScript `.prototype` work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/572897/1048572)

Comment: This [tool](http://maurizzzio.github.io/PojoViz/public/vulcanize.html#render/object) analyzes most of the JavaScript structures you throw at it in runtime :)

Comment: @bits Which tool did you use to do this diagram ? ,

Comment: @RoyiNamir I made the diagram using my own tool in NodeJS. I made it several years ago to help myself learn all these intricacies of Javascript. In that tool you can punch in some (small) javascript code, and indicate which objects you are primarily interested in. And then it generates the diagram (using GraphViz) to best of its knowledge. Since then, I have managed to convert it from NodeJS to regular Javascript, so it works in browser without any dependencies. If there is any interest I can find time to clean it up, and upload it on github.

Comment: @bits I would love to see the JS ( browser) version for this. you can see my email in the profile.

Comment: @Royi Namir I have uploaded [jsViz](https://github.com/shobhitg/jsViz) on github. Here is the [demo site](http://shobhitg.github.io/jsViz/). Please don't mind how unmaintained (and dirty) the actual code is. Its super old project which I haven't touched in forever.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\_\_proto\_\_ VS. prototype in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript)

Answer (score 222, accepted):

I've been trying to wrap my head around this recently and finally came up with this "map" that I think sheds full light over the matter

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFzI3.png
[image]

I know I'm not the first one making this up but it was more interesting figuring it out that finding it :-). Anyway, after that I found e.g. this another diagram that I think says basicly the same:

[Javascript object layout](http://www.mollypages.org/tutorials/js.mp)

The most surprising thing for me was discovering that `Object.__proto__` points to `Function.prototype`, instead of `Object.prototype`, but I'm sure there's a good reason for that :-)

I paste the code mentioned in the image here as well for if anyone wants to test it. Note that some properties are added to the objects for making easy to know where we are after some jumps:

```
Object.O1='';
Object.prototype.Op1='';

Function.F1 = '';
Function.prototype.Fp1 = '';

Cat = function(){};
Cat.C1 = '';
Cat.prototype.Cp1 = '';

mycat = new Cat();
o = {};

// EDITED: using console.dir now instead of console.log
console.dir(mycat);
console.dir(o);
```

Comment: @utsaina Very cool. Checkout another [graphical representation](http://i.imgur.com/IkxPv.png) of the code which OP posted. And I think our diagrams are in agreement in terms of technical details.

Comment: The reason why `Object.__proto__` points to `Function.prototype` is because `Object()` by itself is a native function that instantiates an empty object. Therefore, `Object()` is a function. You'll find that all the other major native types' `__proto__` properties point to `Function.prototype`. `Object`, `Function`, `String`, `Number`, and `Array` all inherit the Function prototype.

Comment: @drodsou your 2nd link is awesome. Do check it out now please ;) http://www.mollypages.org/misc/js.mp Nice explanation :D

Comment: @Swivel " Therefore, Object() is a function" - did you mean to say Object is a function? without ()

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Correct. `Object` itself is a function; the result of executing callable `Object` (i.e., return value of running `Object()`) is not a function.

Comment: Thanks, your map is really helpful! I created a gist based on your semantics to show 1. how the relationships behave when Cat inherits from Animal and 2. the equivalence between ES2015/ES6 classes and ES5 objects: https://gist.github.com/philipstanislaus/bad92373edee1d45887f06ce6fa260eb

Comment: typeof Object returns "function"

Answer (score 69):

`constructor` is a pre-defined [[DontEnum]] property of the object pointed to by the `prototype` property of a function object and will initially point to the function object itself.

`__proto__` is equivalent to the internal [[Prototype]] property of an object, ie its actual prototype.

When you create an object with the `new` operator, its internal [[Prototype]] property will be set to the object pointed to by the constructor function's `prototype` property.

This means that `.constructor` will evaluate to `.__proto__.constructor`, ie the constructor function used to create the object, and as we have learned, the `protoype` property of this function was used to set the object's [[Prototype]].

It follows that `.constructor.prototype.constructor` is identical to `.constructor` (as long as these properties haven't been overwritten); see [here](http://joost.zeekat.nl/constructors-considered-mildly-confusing.html) for a more detailed explanation.

If `__proto__` is available, you can walk the actual prototype chain of the object. There's no way to do this in plain ECMAScript3 because JavaScript wasn't designed for deep inheritance hierarchies.

Comment: That 'here' link is the gold standard.  Go there if you want the full description.

Comment: Nice catch with `.constructor.prototype` chaining. I was also unclear for me, while I didn't saw that `.constructor` is equal `.__proto__.constructor`. Which simply means cycling between constructor function and it's prototype.

Answer (score 32):

The Prototypal Inheritance in JavaScript is based on `__proto__` property in a sense that each object is inheriting the contents of the object referenced by its `__proto__` property.

The `prototype` property is special only for `Function` objects and only when using `new` operator to call a `Function` as constructor. In this case, the created object's `__proto__` will be set to constructor's `Function.prototype`.

This means that adding to `Function.prototype` will automatically reflect on all objects whose `__proto__` is referencing the `Function.prototype`.

Replacing constructor's `Function.prototype` with another object will **not** update `__proto__` property for any of the already existing objects.

Note that `__proto__` property should not be accessed directly, [Object.getPrototypeOf(object)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) should be used instead.

To answer the first question, I've created a bespoke diagram of `__proto__` and `prototype` references, unfortunately stackoverflow does not allow me to add the image with "less than 10 reputation". Maybe some other time.

[Edit]
The figure uses `[[Prototype]]` instead of `__proto__` because that is how ECMAScript specification refers to internal objects. I hope you can figure everything out.

Here are some hints to help you understand the figure:

```
red    = JavaScript Function constructor and its prototype
violet = JavaScript Object constructor and its prototype
green  = user-created objects
         (first created using Object constructor or object literal {},
          second using user-defined constructor function)
blue   = user-defined function and its prototype
         (when you create a function, two objects are created in memory:
          the function and its prototype)
```

Note that `constructor` property does not exist in created objects, but is inherited from the prototype.

[image]

Comment: @xorcus Can you please explain this : `new MyFunction()` creates an object  instance which its `__proto__` should refer to its ctor prototype which is `MyFunction.prototype.` So why does `MyFunction.prototype.__proto__` referes to `Object.prototype` ? it should referene (like my first sample) to its ctor's prototype which is `MyFunction.prototype` (notice that `MyFunction.prototype` is an instnace of `Myfunction`)

Comment: @Royi Namir: MyFunction.prototype.__proto__ referes to Object.prototype because MyFunction.prototype is an object. Object.prototype is inherited by all objects (normally, that's where the prototype chain of inheritance ends). I do not agree that MyFunction.prototype is an instance of MyFunction. obj instanceof MyFunction <=> MyFunction.prototype.isPrototypeOf(obj) <=> MyFunction.prototype exists in the obj prototype chain. That is not the case for MyFunction.prototype object

Answer (score 15):

**`Object` is Eve, and `Function` is Adam, Adam (`Function`) uses his bone (`Function.prototype`) to create Eve (`Object`).  Then who created Adam (`Function`)? -- The Inventor of the JavaScript language :-).**

According to utsaina's  answer, I want to add more useful info.

> The most surprising thing for me was discovering that `Object.__proto__`
>   points to `Function.prototype`, instead of `Object.prototype`, but I'm
>   sure there's a good reason for that :-)

It should NOT be.  `Object.__proto__` should NOT point to `Object.prototype`. Instead, the instance of `Object` `o`, `o.__proto__` should point to `Object.prototype`.

(Forgive me for using the terms `class` and `instance` in JavaScript, but you know it :-)

I think the class `Object` itself is an instance of `Function`, that's why `Object.__proto__ === Function.prototype`. Therefore: `Object` is Eve, and `Function` is Adam, Adam (`Function`) uses his bone (`Function.prototype`) to create Eve (`Object`).

Furthermore, even the class `Function` itself is an instance of `Function` itself, that is `Function.__proto__ === Function.prototype`, that's also why `Function === Function.constructor`

Further furthermore, the regular class `Cat` is an instance of `Function`, that is `Cat.__proto__ === Function.prototype`.

The reason for the above is, when we create a class in JavaScript, actually, we are just creating a function, which should be an instance of `Function`.  `Object` and `Function` are just special, but they are still classes, while `Cat` is a regular class.

**As a matter of factor, in Google Chrome JavaScript engine, the following 4:**

- `Function.prototype`
- `Function.__proto__`
- `Object.__proto__`
- `Cat.__proto__`

They are all `===` (absolutely equal) to the other 3, and their value is `function Empty() {}`

```
> Function.prototype
  function Empty() {}
> Function.__proto__
  function Empty() {}
> Object.__proto__
  function Empty() {}
> Cat.__proto__
  function Empty() {}
> Function.prototype === Function.__proto__
  true
> Function.__proto__ === Object.__proto__
  true
> Object.__proto__ === Cat.__proto__
  true
```

OK. Then who creates the special `function Empty() {}` (`Function.prototype`)?  Think about it :-)

Comment: Agree with that, except for the last one thing: 

what is `function Empty() {}` you refer to being equal to Function.prototype, etc?, what is the code you used in chrome console?

Comment: I corrected the last one thing that you pointed out.  Their value is `function Empty() {}` in Google Chrome. I also added the console output.

Comment: all functions are instanceof Function, and therefore, all functions inherit (`_ _proto_ _`) from Function.prototype. It is as simple as that :)

Comment: Sorry for commenting on old thread. But are they created by Inventor of Language?

Answer (score 7):

I really don't know why people didn't correct you about where the actual problem in your understanding.

This would make a lot easier for you to spot the problem

So let's see what's going on :

```
var newtoy = new Gadget("webcam", "black")

newtoy 
  .constructor //newtoy's constructor function is newtoy ( the function itself)
    .prototype // the function has a prototype property.( all functions has)
      .constructor // constructor here is a **property** (why ? becuase you just did `prototype.constructor`... see the dot ? )  ! it is not(!) the constructor function  !!! this is where your mess begins. it points back to the constructor function itself ( newtoy function)
         .prototype // so again we are at line 3 of this code snippet
            .constructor //same as line 4 ...
                .prototype 
                 rating = 3
```

Great , so now let's look at this `__proto__`

Before that , please remember 2 things regarding `__proto__`  :

1. When you create an object with the `new` operator, its internal `[[Prototype]]`/`proto__` property will be set to the `prototype` property(1) of   its `constructor function` or "creator" if you like .
2. Hard coded  within JS — : `Object.prototype.__proto__` is `null`.

Let's refer to these 2 points as "`bill`"

```
newtoy
     .__proto__ // When `newtoy` was created , Js put __proto__'s value equal to the value of the cunstructor's prototype value. which is `Gadget.prototype`.
       .__proto__ // Ok so now our starting point is `Gadget.prototype`. so  regarding "bill" who is the constructor function now? watch out !! it's a simple object ! a regular object ! prototype is a regular object!! so who is the constructor function of that object ? Right , it's the `function Object(){...}`.  Ok .( continuing "bill" ) does it has a `prototype` property ? sure. all function has. it's `Object.prototype`. just remember that when Gadget.prototype was created , it's internal `__proto__` was refered to `Object.prototype` becuase as "bill" says :"..will be set to the `prototype` property of   its `constructor function`"
          .__proto__ // Ok so now our satrting point is `Object.prototype`. STOP. read bullet 2.Object.prototype.__proto__ is null by definition. when Object.prototype ( as an object) was created , they SET THE __PROTO__ AS NULL HARDCODED
```

Better?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: `__proto__` is a reference to the `prototype` property of the constructor that created the object.

### Objects in JavaScript

A JavaScript object is a built-in type for a *collection* of zero or more properties. Properties are containers that hold other objects, primitive values, or functions.

### Constructors in JavaScript

Functions are regular objects (which implement `[[Call]]` in ECMA-262 terms) with the additional capability of being callable but play another role in JavaScript: they become constructors (*factories* for objects) if invoked via the `new` operator. Constructors are thus a rough analog to classes in other languages.

Every JavaScript function is actually an instance of the `Function` built-in function object that has a special property named `prototype` used to implement prototype-based inheritance and shared properties. Every object created by a constructor function has an *implicit* reference (called the prototype or `__proto__`) to the value of its constructor `prototype`.

The constructor `prototype` is a sort of *blueprint* for building objects since every object created by the constructor inherits a reference to its `prototype`.

### The prototype chain

An object specifies its prototype via the internal property `[[Prototype]]` or `__proto__`. The prototype relationship between two objects is about inheritance: every object can have another object as its prototype. The prototype may be the `null` value.

The chain of objects connected by the `__proto__` property is called the *prototype chain*. When a reference is made to a property in an object, that reference is to the property encountered in the first object in the prototype chain that contains a property of that name. The prototype chain behaves as if it were a single object.

[image: prototype-inheritance.jpg]

Whenever you try to access a property in an object, JavaScript starts the search for it in that object and continues with its prototype, the prototype's prototype and so on until the property is encountered or if `__proto__` holds the value `null`.

> This type of inheritance using the prototype chain is often called *delegation* to avoid confusion with other languages using the class chain.

Almost all objects are instances of `Object`, because `Object.prototype` is last in their prototype chain. But `Object.prototype` is not an instance of `Object` because `Object.prototype.__proto__` holds the value `null`.

You can also create an object with a `null` prototype like this:

```js
var dict = Object.create(null);
```

Such an object is a better map (dictionary) than a literal object, which is why this pattern is sometimes called the *dict* pattern (*dict* for dictionary).

Note: literal objects created using `{}` are instances of `Object` since `({}).__proto__` is a reference to `Object.prototype`.

Comment: Please cite the source of the quotes and artifacts you are using. The picture seems to come from https://giamir.com/pseudoclasses-and-prototypal-inheritance-in-JS, do you have copyright on it?

Answer (score 2):

Every functions creates it's prototype.
And when we create an object using that function constructor then the **__proto__** property of my object will start pointing to the prototype of that function.

Comment: I think you meant to say the `__proto__` property.

Comment: Yes. I meant __proto__ property of an object. I hope the information was useful.

Answer (score 2):

If all those figures were overwhelming, let's take a look what the properties mean.

#### `STH.prototype`

When creating a new function, there is an empty object being created in parallel and linked to the function with `[[Prototype]]` chain. To access this object, we use  `prototype` property of the function.

```
function Gadget() {}
// in background, new object has been created
// we can access it with Gadget.prototype
// it looks somewhat like {constructor: Gadget}
```

*Bear in mind that `prototype` property is only available for functions.*

#### STH.constructor

The prototype object mentioned above has no properties except for one - `constructor`. This property represents a function that created the prototype object.

```
var toy = new Gadget();
```

When creating `Gadget` function, we created an object like `{constructor: Gadget}` as well - that is nothing like `Gadget.prototype`. As `constructor` refers to a function that created an object prototype, `toy.constructor` represents `Gadget` function. We write `toy.constructor.prototype` and we are getting `{constructor: Gadget}` again.

Therefore, there's a vicious circle: you can use `toy.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype` and it always will be `Gadget.prototype`.

```
toy
.constructor    // Gadget
.prototype    // {constructor: Gadget}
.constructor    // Gadget
.prototype    // {constructor: Gadget}
// ...
```

#### STH.__proto__

While `prototype`is a property specific for functions, `__proto__` is available for all objects as it lays in `Object.prototype`. It refers to prototype of a function that can create an object.

```
[].__proto__ === Array.prototype
// true

({}).__proto === Object.prototype
// true
```

Here, `toy.__proto__` is `Gadget.prototype`. As `Gadget.prototype` is an object (`{}`) and objects are created with `Object` function (see the example above), we get `Object.prototype`. This is the higher object in JavaScript and its `__proto__` can only indicate `null`.

```
toy
.__proto__    // Gadget.prototype (object looking like {constructor: Gadget})
.__proto__    // Object.prototype (topmost object in JS)
.__proto__    // null - Object.prototype is the end of any chain
```

Answer (score 0):

### Prototypes in JavaScript are confusing for Everyone

A *constructor* on any type (Object, String, Array, etc) is *initially* connected with the `Function Object` that creates them. Once the object types value/objects are created, only then are they assigned their own prototypes, which is a unique property and object the Functions constructor creates when each value is created. But the *prototyopes* of all objects/types (Object, String, Array, etc) in JavaScript starting out are all `Function.prototype`. They all derive from functions and their constructors needed to create instances of objects and primitive values in memory! It is not till their values get created by their function constructors that they get assigned their own *unique prototypes*, both the "prototyoe" property and the Object prototype they inherit from.

*This is what 99% of online web pages on the Internet do not tell you!*

For example, the `Number` (or String Array, Boolean, etc.) type always has a constructor, or `Number.constructor`, which derives from the `Function Object` assigned to the "Number" type. This is why "Number" is called an "Constructor". So, its prototype is `Function.prototype` when you check. Once its function or constructor has built a true `Number` primitive or type, its assigned its own unique prototype of `Number.prototype`. Let's prove that below!

Here is a simpler explanation. Below is how most objects in JavaScript inherit starting with null down to the object type:

```
String   < Function < Object < null
Array    < Function < Object < null
Object   < Function < Object < null
Function < Function < Object < null
```

Here is proof!
Below I am just asking for the prototype found for each object. Note: `Object.prototype.toString.call()` just tells us the string name of the prototype:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(String);// [object Function]
Object.prototype.toString.call(Array);// [object Function]
Object.prototype.toString.call(Object);// [object Function]
Object.prototype.toString.call(Function);// [object Function]

Object.prototype.toString.call(String.__proto__);// [object Function]
Object.prototype.toString.call(Array.__proto__);// [object Function]
Object.prototype.toString.call(Object.__proto__);// [object Function]
Object.prototype.toString.call(Function.__proto__);// [object Function]

Object.prototype.toString.call(String.__proto__.__proto__);// [object Object]
Object.prototype.toString.call(Array.__proto__.__proto__);// [object Object]
Object.prototype.toString.call(Object.__proto__.__proto__);// [object Object]
Object.prototype.toString.call(Function.__proto__.__proto__);// [object Object]

Object.prototype.toString.call(String.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__);// [object Null]
Object.prototype.toString.call(Array.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__);// [object Null]
Object.prototype.toString.call(Object.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__);// [object Null]
Object.prototype.toString.call(Function.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__);// [object Null]
```

Please note that the string "[object Function]" is saying that the "prototype" or parent object for the type was "Function.prototype". So it a representation of the underlying prototype parent objects assigned at each level. Now let's explain this in more depth...

A ***prototype*** in JavaScript is a word that means the following:

- All Objects in JavaScript ultimately inherit from a series of prototypes or "base classes" that assign their various properties and features through inheritance. This cascades down a tree to the child at the bottom. In JavaScript ALL OBJECTS ultimately inherit from the *Object.prototype* which is close to the top of that inheritance tree.
- The term "prototype" means a special object with properties and methods inherited by child objects
- "prototype" is also a special property given to all Objects in JavaScript that assigns a given object as the parent prototype to a child but also grants access to changing the prototype. It controls the actual prototype assigned to a child object, but also acts like a true Class Property in that you can use it to manipulate the prototype of a child object. I do not recommend you do this, but you can modify the original Object.prototype inherited by all object by adding new properties using a simple property addition or adding properties via a *Object Literal* containing properties:

```
    Object.prototype.myproperty = "Hello World";
    Object.prototype.myobjectproperties = {text1: "Hello", text2: "World"};
```

- "prototype" the property is expressed in combination with the Child Object name as "MyObjectType.prototype". This new name is now both a identifier for the parent prototype and also a tool to change it. But it is NOT a reference to the actual prototype object! (That is done below using __proto__). It is assigned to all new objects when created of that type. It is first assigned to the function constructor that built the object, then passed to the object the function constructor creates.
- "__proto__" is a reference to the actual prototype object assigned to the child. Its also a property but its a reference. So its used to go up the tree of prototypes objects inherited by a child object and access them and their properties. This example below goes up the tree from an object literal created and ends at the top with "null":

```
    alert({}.__proto__.__proto__);// null
```

### Weirdness in Prototype

So, in JavaScript inheritance, everything starts with a Function type! Why is that? Its because you cannot create any of the object "types" (Object, Array, Function, String, etc.) without a Function. And when you do, they still get constructed from a "constructor" called somewhere in a function. A Function and its constructor is what not only creates new objects from types, but also assigns the "prototype" property, the "__proto__" property, and the actual tree of inherited *prototypes* or objects the child object will use.

There are two states of objects in JavaScript, the "types" and the actual instantiated Objects. That is why "Object" is not the same as a created Object as "const x = {}". And that is why the "type" starts out with a different inheritance or prototypes from its final one.

Check this out!

```
// The Array type has a prototype of "Function.prototype"
alert(Object.prototype.toString.call(Array));// [object Function]

// But an instance of an Array object has a NEW prototype of "Array.prototype" that the function prototype's constructor created for the object!
const myarray = [];
alert(Object.prototype.toString.call(myarray));// [object Array]
```

So what happened?

It turns out the FUNCTION CONSTRUCTOR creates and assigns the final `prototype` when the object is created. But that custom prototype can be modified both before and after the array object is created with many more properties, objects, etc. So the final assigned prototype is set by the constructor of the Function object which as shown above was the Array types initial prototype.

So realize, **the `Function.prototype` is the primary prototype of all Object types in JavaScript**! It lies underneath all objects, but is a tool to creating the final instantiated object that is assigned its own prototype when created. Note that the "Array.prototype" has a parent prototype of `Object.prototype` who has a parent of "null". So the `Object.prototype` remains the top parent inherited by all these objects. But in the creation of them the constructor changes the immediate parent of all child objects when new objects get created.

Note that the `Function.prototype` gets many of its features from its own Object.prototype it too inherits. The prototype it builds for your created objects are also made from this parent prototype. So in the end. the `Object.prototype` provides the goodies needed for Function types and all types to get created and manage the prototype assigned to them. Just remember **Function** like **Object** is a special pre-built type with special tools and features needed to create all types of objects!

Last test....lets see how prototype works for CUSTOM OBJECTS we create. The example below proves that the function constructor (part of the *Function.prototype*) assigns the **"prototype"** property to the created objects BUT can be customized with various properties and methods *before* or *after* being assigned to the objects prototype of `MyCustomObject.prototype`. This shows that the final prototype of your object need not be a static copy of the `Object.prototype`'s inherited properties, but can be something you create that is entirely new!

```
let newPet;
function Pet() {
  this.fourlegs = true;
}

var Cat = {
  type : "cat"
}

var Dog = {
  type : "dog"
}

// We can see the prototype our constructor created for us
// and modify it as we like! Here we assigned it to an object
// which only means the prototype will merge "Cat" object's
// properties into the Pet.prototype.
Pet.prototype = Cat;

newPet = new Pet();
alert(newPet.type);// cat - inherited the Cat Object's properties in the prototype

Pet.prototype = Dog;

newPet = new Pet();
alert(newPet.type);// dog - inherited the Dog Object's properties in the prototype

alert(newPet.fourlegs);// true - this shows, even though you replace prototype, it ADDs the new types but does NOT erase the existing object properties! This must mean "prototype" is dynamically additive and rebuilt until the final "Pet" prototype is complete.

// Now change the "Pet.prototype" so all new objects have a new property.
Pet.prototype.furcolor = "white";
newPet = new Pet();
alert(newPet.furcolor);// "white"

// So you can see the "Pet.prototype" is dynamic, something you can tell the function constructor to modify!
```

Answer (score 0):

We can put it really simply:

`Prototype` is used during object creation to set up the initial prototype.

`__proto__` is used for ongoing inheritance after object creation.