# What is the default prototype for custom function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
function f()
{
}

alert (f.prototype); // returns something like [object Object]
```

My understanding is by default the prototype of custom function should be null or undefined, can someone shed some light? thanks!

#### See also: [How does __proto__ differ from constructor.prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650764/proto-vs-constructor-prototype)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `prototype` property of function objects is automatically created, is simply an empty object with the `{DontEnum}` and `{DontDelete}` property attributes, you can see how function objects are created in the specification:

- [13.2 Creating Function Objects](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-13.2)

Pay attention to the steps 9, 10 and 11:

9) Create a new object as would be constructed by the expression `new Object()`.

10) Set the constructor property of Result(9) to F. This property is given attributes `{ DontEnum }`.

11) Set the prototype property of F to Result(9). This property is given attributes as specified in [15.3.5.2](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.3.5.2).

You can see that this is true by:

```
function f(){
  //...
}

f.hasOwnProperty('prototype'); // true, property exist on f

f.propertyIsEnumerable('prototype'); // false, because the { DontEnum } attribute

delete f.prototype; // false, because the { DontDelete } attribute
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a link describing object inheritance:

http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

http://www.mollypages.org/misc/js.mp
[image]
<sub>(source: [mollypages.org](http://www.mollypages.org/misc/jsobj.jpg))</sub>

Comment: you mean every time you declare a function Foo, system or JavaScript engine will automatically create a Foo.prototype object for us?

Comment: @Ding: yes. That way when you create an object using your function as a constructor (`new f()`) the object you create will have Object in its prototype chain (because its prototype's prototype *is* Object). Be careful about confusing an object's prototype (the object it "inherits" from) with a function's `prototype` property - they're not the same thing. See CMS's answer for the gritty details if you're interested...

Answer (score 0):

It's not undefined because you just defined it.  Just because your `function f()`  object is still *empty* doesn't mean it's not defined.  It's just defined to have no contents.