# is there corresponding stuff in IE for Firefox __proto__?

Tags: javascript

is there corresponding stuff in IE for Firefox `__proto__` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650764/how-does-proto-differ-from-constructor-prototype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No.

<sub>More characters</sub>

Answer (score 1):

As a getter, you can use [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff877835%28v=vs.94%29.aspx), introduced by ECMAScript5 and supported since IE9.

Moreover, [`__proto__`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn342818%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) and [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#Object_static_methods_Object.setPrototypeOf) are supported since IE11.