# [[Prototype]] vs prototype: ..what is the difference? (MyCons.__proto__ === MyCons.prototype) equals FALSE

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototype-programming

It seems like there is a difference here...

Let's say we have `function MyConstructor() {}`

MyConstructor's `[[Prototype]]` is `Function.prototype`, **not** `MyConstructor.prototype.`

In other *(non-standard/"console.log-able")* words:
`MyConstructor.__ proto__` **is not** MyConstructor's `MyConstructor.prototype`

**TRY THIS:**

```
function MyConstructor() {};
(MyConstructor.__proto__ === MyConstructor.prototype); //false?! why?
```

**Why is this so? Can someone explain it to me the *difference*?**

Comment: See also: [`__proto__` vs. `prototype` in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9959727/1048572), [How does JavaScript `.prototype` work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/572897/1048572) and [How does `.__proto__` differ from `.constructor.prototype`?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/650764/1048572)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Think of it like this. `MyConstructor` is a function object, so it was created by `Function`; therefore its `[[Prototype]]` (or `__proto__`) is identical to `Function.prototype`.

In the same way, `var myObj = new MyConstructor()` creates an object `myObj` with a `[[Prototype]]` identical to `MyConstructor.prototype`.

To put it another way, functions have a `prototype` property, and when you invoke functions with `new`, they will construct an object having a `[[Prototype]]` identical to the constructor function's `prototype` property... however a function's `prototype` property is not the same thing as its `[[Prototype]]` (or `__proto__`) property, because a function follows the same rules as other objects and gets its internal `[[Prototype]]` property from the function that constructed it (which is always `Function`, incidentally).

---

To explain further, `[[Prototype]]` and `prototype` have entirely different purposes. `[[Prototype]]` is used when resolving an object's properties. If an object doesn't have a property, its `[[Prototype]]` is checked, and then that object's `[[Prototype]]`, and so on, until either a property is found or you hit the end of the prototype chain.

In contrast, `prototype` is the mechanism by which you assign `[[Prototype]]` properties to objects, since you can't access them directly other than with the non-standard `__proto__` property.

Since functions are objects, they have both a `[[Prototype]]` internal property, used to resolve properties as with normal objects, and a `prototype` property, which is assigned as the `[[Prototype]]` of new objects constructed by the function.

Answer (score 2):

this code will show it very clear:

```js
var obj = {};
var arr = [];
var fun = function() {};    

A:     
console.log(obj.prototype);
console.log(arr.prototype);
console.log(fun.prototype);

B:
console.log(arr.__proto__);
console.log(fun.__proto__);

C:
console.log(obj.__proto__);
console.log(arr.__proto__.__proto__);
console.log(fun.__proto__.__proto__);
console.log(fun.prototype.__proto__);
```

the chrome console of that is:

[image]

the meaning of that:

A. in JavaScript 'prototype' is special object that exists just in functions - for making function constructor (for your question - that's why 'prototype' it's not equal to '**proto**').

B. array and functions has the they're own '**proto**' with all they're proprieties and methods that built in in JavaScript.

C. everything in JavaScript truly inside they're objects, so the 'prototype.**proto**' of functions, or  '**proto**.**proto**' of functions and arrays are all equal the '**proto**' of an object.

Comment: Wait, that code DOES work. As in, the "A: " and "B: " lines work. I just did "a:5" on in the console and it printed "5" but didn't create an "a" global variable. I'm confused. Normally you use these during object literals, but what is the use OUTSIDE of them? You can't use them as a label and 'goto' them or anything, so... Do you know?

Comment: So, I figured it out finally after finding the right way to search for it which was literally the phrase that matched this result: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34190256/js-colon-syntax-outside-of-an-object-literal. So, it looks like Javascript has labels for CONTINUE statements that act as a goto ONLY. Honestly, that's one of the only valid uses of goto in my opinion. It's not really as bad as people make it out to be in modern languages like C# anymore since you can only do it in the same scope (thus preventing 99.9% of the speghetti code). It's just that there are ALWAYS better ways.

Comment: One last thing, it appears someone 'added' full 'goto' functionality into javascript. It works, you just have to do "[lbl] a:" instead of just a: and then run it through gotojs to have it transform it to the output. IF it's in a script tag on your site you can have all of them automaticall parsed (or using a specific 'type' like 'text/gotojs'). Interesting.

Answer (score -1):

Inspired by another answer, and to complete it:

```
var obj = {name: 'Ali'};
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var date = new Date();
var func = function(){console.log('Hi!')};
var arrowFunc = ()=>{};

obj.prototype === undefined;
arr.prototype === undefined;
date.prototype === undefined;
func.prototype != undefined;
func.hasOwnProperty('prototype') === true;
arrowFunc.prototype === undefined;
arrowFunc.hasOwnProperty('prototype') === false;

obj.__proto__ === Object.prototype;
arr.__proto__ === Array.prototype;
date.__proto__ === Date.prototype;
func.__proto__ === Function.prototype;
arrowFunc.__proto__ === Function.prototype;

Array.prototype.__proto__ === Object.prototype;
Date.prototype.__proto__ === Object.prototype;
Function.prototype.__proto__ === Object.prototype;

Object.prototype__proto__ === undefined;
```