# Setting prototype for Object Literal

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

Let's say I have the following code;

```
var A = {a:10};
var B = {b:20};
B.prototype = A;
alert(B.a);
```

I am getting undefined for B.a . 
Am I doing something wrong? How do I set the prototype for object literal ?

I know how to do for Constructor object. So the following code works perfect

```
function A(){this.a=10}
function B(){this.b=20}
B.prototype = new A();
b = new B;
alert(b.a);
```

How do I do it for object literal ?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7015693/989121

Comment: short answer: you cannot

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/java-script-what-is-the-difference-between-proto-and-prototype or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work?lq=1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650764/how-does-proto-differ-from-constructor-prototype?rq=1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451881/prototype-vs-prototype-what-is-the-difference-mycons-proto-myco/9451979#9451979

Answer (score 12):

Objects inherit from their **constructor's** prototype property, not their own. The constructor's prototype is assigned to the internal [`[[Prototype]]`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2) property that is available in some browsers as the [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) property.

So for `b` to inherit from `a`, you need to put `a` on `b`'s inheritance chain, e.g.

Classic prototype inheritance:

```
var a = {a: 'a'};
function B(){}
B.prototype = a;

var b = new B();
alert(b.a); // a
```

Using ES5 Object.create:

```
var a = {a: 'a'};
var b = Object.create(a);

alert(b.a); // a
```

Using Mozilla `__proto__`:

```
var a = {a: 'a'};
var b = {};
b.__proto__ = a;

alert(b.a); // a
```

Comment: Looking at the ES5 Object.create example, how would you augment `a`, once `a` is on `b`'s inheritance/prototype chain?

Comment: `a`'s properties need to be augmented directly, e.g. `a.foo = 'foo'`. Assigning to `b` will create a property of `b`, even if a same–named property exists on `a`.

Comment: @RobG Might reword that as "assigning to `b` will create a property on `b`" instead of "property of `b`".

Answer (score 3):

The prototype property is usually present in a Function object. This prototype should be an object, and this object is used to define the properties of an object created with a constructor.

```
// Plain object, no prototype property here.
var plainObject = {one: 1, two: 2};

// Constructor, a prototype property will be created by default
var someConstruct = function() {

  // Constructor property
  someConstruct.constructProp = "Some value";

  // Constructor's prototype method
  someConstruct.prototype.hello = function() {
    return "Hello world!";
  }
};

// Another constructor's prototype method
someConstruct.prototype.usefulMethod = function() {
  return "Useful string";
}

var someInstance = new someConstruct();
console.log(someInstance.hello()); // => Hello world!
console.log(someInstance.usefulMethod()); // => Useful string

console.log(someConstruct.constructProp); // => Some value
console.log(someConstruct.prototype); // => {usefulMethod: function, hello: function}

console.log(plainObject.prototype); // => undefined
```

So, plain objects have no prototypes.
Functions which work as constructors do have prototypes. These prototypes are used to fill an instance created with each construct.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: What is the difference of defining a propert directly Vs on the prototype....like in the above case someConstruct.constructProp Vs someConstruct.prototype.somePrototypeProperty

Answer (score 0):

Only when using `Function` object that prototype is used, e.g. when you use a constructor. But no need of that for object literals.

Both of them are very good techniques, so it depends on what you want to do in a project and the JavaScript pattern you are using or like.