# What is the portable way of setting prototype property after an object is created?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have a JavaScript object created from JSON.  I really need to set its prototype property to be a different object because of JS5 getters and setters.  Here is an example of what I need that works on Chrome:

```
function MyObj() { }
MyObj.prototype = { 
  get myProp : function () { return this._myProp; },
  set myProp : function (arg) { this._myProp = arg; }
}

... stuff ...

var instance = JSON.parse(result);
instance.constructor = MyObj;
instance.__proto__ = MyObj.prototype;
```

With this code, I can get and set properties on `instance` using the getters and setters defined in the prototype.  However, this is not portable and will not work on IE, (nor node, I think).

What is the proper and portable way of doing this?

Comment: define your use of "portable" in this use case please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting prototype for Object Literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472005/setting-prototype-for-object-literal)

Comment: @GGG Missed that question when I searched earlier.  It doesn't exactly answer what I am trying to do.  It is suggesting that I use Object.create(...), but since JSON is instantiating the object, I cannot.

Comment: @BrianVanderbusch Should work on any ECMA5 compatible runtime.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg if you have `get` and `set`, I'm pretty sure you have `__proto__`, no?

Comment: so you're trying to extend the JSON object by implementing the interface of your own custom object?

Comment: He's trying to assign a prototype to an existing object, a subject that has been discussed here ad nauseum. We have `__proto__` and we narrowly missed having a horribly awkward triangle operator. We have `Object.create()` as a workaround, and its predecessor, the "prototype dance." Those are pretty much the only options, it's not going to change.

Comment: @GGG unfortunately, no.  get and set are ECMA5 compliant. `__proto__` is not.

Comment: @BrianVanderbusch Exactly.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg ah, I see, IE 9 and 10 have get and set don't they... I realize `__proto__` is not in ES5, but I was thinking that `get` and `set` only worked in some subset of browsers that are not IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think the other way around:

Create a new instance of `MyObj` and then copy the properties of `instance` to it. Or give `MyObj` a constructor that does that, when you provide it with an argument:

```
function MyObj(instance) {
 if (instance) {
   //copy properties
```

This way you may be even able to do

```
var instance = new MyObj(JSON.parse(result));
```

Comment: I like this idea.  I will try it out.  However, I also need to be able to support a different kind of constructor, like this: new MyObj(prop1, prop2, prop3);  But I should be able to overload the constructor.

Comment: this was my thought as well.. beat me to the punch!

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg: if prop1 is not an object you can check its type. If it is an object, then you know it's the instance.

Comment: In the end, my solution most closely looks like yours and so I am giving you the correct answer.  I decided to go with a separate revive() function defined on MyObj.  I don't like the idea of overloading constructors and functions in JS.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a JSON reviver function.

```
function revive(json) {

  var m = new MyObj(), y;

  return JSON.parse(json, function(k, v){ 
    if (!y) y = this; 
    return k == "" ? m : this == y ? m[k] = v : v 
  });

}
```

Call `revive('... a json string ...')`, it will spit out an instance of `MyObj` with the properties defined in the JSON string.

Caveat: this will only work if the first item in your JSON object is a primitive value. If that's not possible in your case, here's a rather ugly workaround:

```
function revive(json) {

  var m = new MyObj(), c = json.charAt(0), y, a;

  if (c == '[') {
    a = json = '[0,' + json.substring(1);
  } else if (c == '{') {
    json = '{"@":0,' + json.substring(1);
  }

  return JSON.parse(json, function(k, v){ 
    if (!y) { y = this; return; } 
    return k == "" ? m : this == y ? m[a ? k - 1 : k] = v : v 
  });

}
```

Comment: Nice.  I had no idea about reviver functions.

Comment: Yeah, this sounded good when I started writing it, but really you might as well just do the usual `JSON.parse` and then copy the properties over. This is more of a curiosity than anything, I guess.

Comment: In the end, I didn't want to use a revive function.  Although a neat idea, I wanted to encapsulate the converting to MyObj in the MyObj code, and not where we get the json string.  Thanks for the answer anyway.