# How prototype method work?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand prototypal inheritance. But unclear with the following code:

```
var obj1 = {
   objMethod : function(){
     return 'name: ' + this.name;
   }
};

var obj2 = {
  [[Prototype]] : obj1,
  name : 'Bhojendra'
};
```

So, to understand what the code is going to say, I've tried:

```
obj2.objMethod();
obj1.objMethod();
```

But throws the error. So, what the code is trying to say about prototype? And how to work with this?

Comment: The "obj2" code does not look like valid JavaScript (even ES6).

Comment: `[[Prototype]]` is an notional "internal property" used by the EMCAScript spec to describe how prototyping behavior works. You cannot set it directly by name; you *can* cause it to be set it at object-creation time when you use `new Constructor` (sets `[[Prototype]]` to `Constructor.prototype`) or with `Object.create(proto)` (sets `[[Prototype]]` to `proto`).

Comment: So, what the book is trying to say me?

Comment: I Would like to know the name of the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is invalid code:

```
var obj2 = {
  [[Prototype]] : obj1,
  name : 'Bhojendra'
};
```

You're using spec language that's not part of actual language syntax.

There's currently no (standard) way to set the prototype object within an object literal, but it is coming in ECMAScript 6.

At that point, you'll be able to do this in browser environments and other environments that decide to support the syntax:

```
var obj2 = {
  __proto__ : obj1,
  name : 'Bhojendra'
};
```

This does currently work in some browsers, but isn't an official syntax until ECMAScript 6 is finalized with its inclusion.

---

So what the language spec is doing by referring to `[[Prototype]]` is it's making a generic reference to the next object in the prototype chain.

For example, let's say I have a constructor like this:

```
function Foo() {
    this.x = 123;
}
```

And we create an object from that constructor like this:

```
var foo = new Foo();
```

Now the `foo` object's prototype chain looks like this:

```
foo --> Foo.prototype --> Object.prototype --> null
```

The `[[Prototype]]` of the `foo` object is the object located at `Foo.prototype`. And so when you look for a property on your `foo` object, if it can't find it, it'll continue the search at the `Foo.prototype` object. It continues down the chain until it either finds your property or runs out of objects to search, and returns `undefined`.

---

So a conceptual, high level model of what prototypal inheritance is would go something like this:

The prototype chain is just a chain of objects. Let's say you want to have an object where if you can't find a property on it, it automatically looks for the property on another object. And let's say that other object is set up to look for it on yet another object. That's the prototype chain.

```
my_obj -> other_obj -> another_obj
```

If you can't find a property on the `my_obj`, it'll automatically search for it on the next object in the chain and so on until it either finds it or returns `undefined`.

JavaScript uses "constructor" functions to set this up in a somewhat weird and confusing way. A clearer way is to set it up using `Object.create()`.

```
var another_obj = {foo: "FOO"}; // `another_obj` inherits from `Object.prototype`

// prototype chain of `another_obj` is...
// another_obj -> Object.prototype -> null


var other_obj = Object.create(another_obj); // `other_obj` inherits from `another_obj`

// prototype chain of `other_obj` is...
// other_obj -> another_obj -> Object.prototype -> null


var my_obj = Object.create(other_obj); // `my_obj` inherits from `other_obj`

// prototype chain of `my_obj` is...
// my_obj -> other_obj -> another_obj -> Object.prototype -> null
```

Comment: Please expand your answer with prototype chain what I'm interested from the book. Thank you.

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal: I've updated it a bit. The prototype chain is just a chain of objects. Let's say you want to have an object where if you can't find a property on it, it automatically looks for the property on another object. And let's say that other object is set up to look for it on yet another object. That's the prototype chain. `my_obj -> other_obj -> another_obj` If you can't find a property on the `my_obj`, it'll automatically search for it on the next object in the chain and so on until it either finds it or returns `undefined`.

Comment: If obj2 inherits from obj1 then obj1 also inherited from obj2 automatically? (confusion with the relation between those objects)

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal: No, the arrows go only in one direction. You can have many objects that all inherit from the same object. Like in the `Foo` constructor example, you can create many objects using `new Foo()`. All those new objects point to `Foo.prototype`, but `Foo.prototype` is unaware of those objects.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one:

```
var obj1 = {
objMethod : function(){
    return 'name: ' + this.name;
    }
};

var obj2 = {
    __proto__ : obj1,
    'name' : 'Bhojendra'
};

console.log(obj2.objMethod());
console.log(obj1.objMethod());
```

The problem is how you define the prototype of the `obj2`.

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472005/setting-prototype-for-object-literal):

> Objects inherit from their constructor's prototype property, not their
>   own. The constructor's prototype is assigned to the internal
>   [[Prototype]] property that is available in some browsers as the
>   **proto** property.