# How can I use an object literal to make an instance of a class without useing the constructor in JavaScript ES6?

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

I am trying to learn JavaScript ES6 which is a very cool language and I thought that I should practice a bit but I am not able to make [an exercise](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/talks/es6_falsyvalues2015/exercises/#Fake_point).
So how can I use object literal to copy a class.

For example the class is:

```
class Point {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x, this.y = y
  }
  add(other) {
    return new Point(this.x + other.x, this.y + other.y)
  }
}
```

And I want to do something here using object literal to make the output true.

```
var fakePoint = YOUR_CODE_HERE
console.log(fakePoint instanceof Point)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll guess that this exercise is looking for a solution that uses [`__proto__` as an object literal key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Prototype_mutation) - as [mentioned in the slides](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/talks/es6_falsyvalues2015/#15):

```
var fakePoint = {
    __proto__: Point.prototype,
    x: Math.random(),
    y: Math.random()
};
console.log(fakePoint instanceof Point)
```

However, [`__proto__` is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36061819/1048572) (both in object literals and as a `Object.prototype` getter / setter) and only available in web browsers as a ES6-standardised legacy feature, so I recommend to avoid such code. The proper solution is to use `Object.create`:

```
var fakePoint = Object.assign(Object.create(Point.prototype), {
    x: Math.random(),
    y: Math.random()
});
console.log(fakePoint instanceof Point)
```

Comment: Would you consider this q a dupe of this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472005/setting-prototype-for-object-literal

Comment: @Li357 Don't think so, none of the answers there uses `__proto__` inside an object literal. Also this question is specifically about ES6.

Comment: @vibhor1997a Good for node, they're standard-compliant! See my second paragraph - it's expected to work only in browsers.

Comment: @Bergi the second one is logging `true`

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's another approach which probably is not what the exercise author intended but which is arguably an object literal:

```
var fakePoint = {
  x: Math.random(),
  y: Math.random(),
  fakeConstructor: Object.defineProperty(Point, Symbol.hasInstance, {
    value(o) { return o.fakeConstructor == this; }
  })
};
console.log(fakePoint instanceof Point)
```

It works by giving `Point` a [custom `hasInstance` implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/hasInstance) which doesn't check the prototype chain but rather the `fakeConstructor` property. One could also use `"x" in o && "y" in o` or something similar. Of course it's horrible to do this side effect as part of an object literal, it would better be written

```
Object.defineProperty(Point, Symbol.hasInstance, {
  value(o) { return o.fakeConstructor == this; /* this === Point */ }
});
var fakePoint = {
  x: Math.random(),
  y: Math.random(),
  fakeConstructor: Point
};
```