# JS colon syntax outside of an object literal?

Tags: javascript

I'm seeing the below function as an example of the babel plugin. What is the `pre:` doing in this function? I've tried with and without it and the result is the same.

```
function warn (message) {
  pre: typeof message === 'string';
  return 'Warning!\n' + message;
}
```

edit: [Babel plugin](https://github.com/codemix/babel-plugin-contracts)

Comment: I think it depends on how the babel plugin works. Do you have a link to it? Looks like it could be some kind of type checking.

Comment: @CoryDanielson Yep good call, added to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) (a type of GOTO primerily used to manipulate loops (e.g. with `continue`) when dealing with nested loops).

In that particular case, it is not doing anything practical since there is no loop and nothing references it.