# Why does isPrototypeOf() return false?

Tags: javascript

I have the below constructors and SubType prototype pointing to an instance of SuperType. When I do `x.isPrototypeOf(SubType.prototype)` it returns `false`. I am confused as I have explicitly set `x` as a prototype for `SubType`. Can someone tell me why this is happening?

```js
function SuperType(){}
    
function SubType(){}

x = new SuperType();

SubType.prototype = x;
SubType.prototype.constructor = SubType;

console.log(x.isPrototypeOf(SubType)) // returns false
console.log(SuperType.prototype.isPrototypeOf(SubType.prototype)) // returns true
```

Comment: Not sure to get my head all clear here, but `x === SubType.prototype` how do you expect it to be its own prototype?

Comment: Updated my question, sorry about that type

Comment: try `console.log(x.isPrototypeOf(new SubType)) ` for example of how it's used.

Comment: Notice that you better should be using `x = Object.create(SuperType.prototype)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\[\[Prototype\]\] vs prototype: ..what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9451881/1048572)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SubType` is a function. What you probably want to check is if an **instance** of SubType would inherit from `x`:

```js
function SuperType(){}
    
function SubType(){}

x = new SuperType();

SubType.prototype = x;
SubType.prototype.constructor = SubType;

const instance = new SubType();
console.log(x.isPrototypeOf(instance)) // returns true
console.log(SuperType.prototype.isPrototypeOf(SubType.prototype)) // returns true
```

Answer (score 2):

It helps to add properties to the objects to see what's happening.  I fixed a little of your code.  You can run this in the console:

```
function SuperType(foo){ this.foo = foo };
function SubType(bar){ this.bar = bar };

var x = new SubType("bar");

SuperType.prototype = x;
SuperType.prototype.constructor = SubType;
```

Now, you asked `x.isPrototypeOf(SuperType)` and it returns false, because `x` is not a property of the class `SuperType`.  But when you instantiate a `SuperType`, `x` is a property of that new object:

```
var y = new SuperType("foo");
console.log(x.isPrototypeOf(y)) // returns true
```

In your example that is true, `SubType.prototype` is a prototype of `SuperType.prototype` and returns true.

```
console.log(SubType.prototype.isPrototypeOf(SuperType.prototype)) // returns true
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is misunderstanding of `prototype` and `__proto__` properties.

Lets modify example above a little

```
function SuperType(){}

function SubType(){}

x = new SuperType();

SubType.prototype = x;
console.log(x.isPrototypeOf(SubType)) // returns false.

// Now most interesting piece
SubType.__proto__ = x;
console.log(x.isPrototypeOf(SubType)) // Now true.
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/fyodor_e82/pen/mgzqKe?editors=0012)

In place of `SubType.__proto__ = x` we may use `Object.setPrototypeOf(SubType, x)` which will yeilds the [same result](https://codepen.io/fyodor_e82/pen/mgzqQV?editors=1012)

The trik is `__proto__` holds real object which is prototype. `prototype` is used only in constructor fucntions for defining prototype for constructed objects. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript))

So if we again modify first example

```
function SuperType(){}

function SubType(){}

x = new SuperType();

SubType.prototype = x;

console.log(x.isPrototypeOf(SubType)) // returns false

var x2 = new SubType();
console.log(x.isPrototypeOf(x2)) // returns true
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/fyodor_e82/pen/qwJVwe)