# Is Object the highest in the prototype chain?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

(`__proto__` property refers to the actual prototype of an object.)

`Object` is a **function** (and also used as a constructor).

Since it is a function, it's constructor should be `Function`.

So, if I wanted some property added to `Object`, I could add it to `Function.prototype`.

But, `Function` is an object and all objects inherit from `Object` in some way.

Is this actually a cyclic relation?

I read this in an MDN page :

`(some function) ---> Function.prototype ---> Object.prototype ---> null`

How can `null` be the `__proto__` of `Object`? Isn't it `Function.prototype` again?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650764/how-does-proto-differ-from-constructor-prototype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading up on this, I think the diagram in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11249437/1418853) answer, answers the question.

Every object in Javascript is has a `__proto__` property which is the same as it's constructor's prototype property.
So, if a property of an object isn't found, it looks it up in it's `__proto__` property and upwards like that, until it either finds it or reaches `null`.

`Object.prototype` is **THE** end of the prototype chain, with `Object.prototype.constructor` being `Object`.

The fact that `Object` is a function, would mean that, `Object.__proto__` is `Function.prototype`(because `Object` could have been created as `new Function()`)

**but** not that `Object.prototype.__proto__` is `Function.prototype`.

So, the `__proto__` chain goes `Function.prototype` --> `Object.prototype` --> `null`

I hope I got it right.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, Function and Object hold the top positions together. Since Function has an Object as it's prototype, and Object, as a constructor, is actually a Function.

This sort of mutual dependency/inheritance is common on fully OO languages, and can become much more complicated that this (rather simple) two-item version. Take a look at [Ruby's inheritance diagram](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Class.html) (in beautiful ascii art!) to see how brain-wrenching it can be :)

The good thing is, you usually don't have to worry about it. It should Just Work™.