# confused with __proto_ and prototype in js

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
Person.prototype.kind = 'person'
var zack = new Person('Zack');
console.log(zack.__proto__ == Person.prototype); //=> true
console.log(zack.__proto__ == zack.prototype) //=> false
</script>
```

Question:

why this line: `console.log(zack.__proto__ == zack.prototype)` shows false? I checked online about the difference between `__proto__` and `prototype`, but it is quite complex, still do not understand. Anyone can give me a simple and clear explantion? Thanks.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650764/how-does-proto-differ-from-constructor-prototype

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `zack.__proto__` is `zack.constructor.prototype`, and `zack.constructor` is `Person`, and `zack` has no property named `prototype` defined.

If you `console.log(zack.prototype)` you will see it is undefined!

So this is what is happening:

```
console.log(zack.__proto__ == Person.prototype); //=> true
```

`zack.__proto__` **is** `Person.prototype`.

```
console.log(zack.__proto__ == zack.prototype) //=> false
```

`zack.__proto__`, being `Person.prototype`, can't be an `undefined` property.

If you want to access prototype of Person from the instantiated variables, you can do a little trick which **I don't recommend**, because it is recursive and succeed in an infinite loop of properties.

```
Person.prototype.prototype = Person.prototype;
```