# Why Function's prototype is a function and why Object inherits from there?

Tags: javascript

```
Function.prototype // function Empty() {}
```

How does it make sense? For example, if we will take the `Number` object, we can see that his prototype (`Number.__proto__`) is `Function.prototype` which includes method like `apply` and `call`. How can I use `Number.apply(..)` if Number's prototype is an empty function and not a regular prototype object like all other prototype? (Number prototype, String prototype, any other custom prototype are an objects. even Object.prototype is an object).

After that, how does it make sense that `Object.__proto__ == Function.prototype`? Object should be the highest object, how it inherits from `Function.prototype` when `Function` inherits from.. `Object.prototype`!

```
Object instanceof Function // true
Function instanceof Object // of course true
Function instanceof Function // true
```

Comment: Number.__proto__?   Instances have a .__proto__ property,  not the constructor

Comment: @JuanMendes, Number is an instance. every object has `__proto__`.

Comment: I think your second point is addressed in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650764/how-does-proto-differ-from-constructor-prototype/11249437#11249437) and its comments.

Comment: I see what you're asking,  typing an answer on my phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Miklos is right, but more simply put:

`Object.__proto__ == Function` means that `Object` itself is a function, because it's the constructor. It doesn't mean that objects that inherits from `Object` will inherit `Function`. An object inherits a constructor's `.prototype`, not its `.__proto__`

In other words

```
function Car (){}
inst = new Car ();
// inst inherits from Car.prototype
// inst.__proto__ == Car.prototype;
// Car inherits from Function.prototype because it is a function
// Car.__proto__ == Function.prototype;
```

But that doesn't mean that `inst` inherits from `Function.prototype`, you can't call `apply` and `call` on it.

```
// This means that Everything that inherits from function will
console.log(`Function.prototype`) === function Empty() {}
```

Another twist

```
// This means that the constructor function (Object)
// inherits from `Function.prototype` That is, you can use call and apply,
// And at a lower language level, you can use () and new on it.
Object instanceof Function // true

// It doesn't mean that instances created from Object inherit 
// from Function.prototype (can't use call/apply)
(new Object()) instanceOf Function ? // false
(new Object()).apply === undefined ? // true

// This means that functions themselves are objects, everything is an object
// They have properties like hasOwnProperty and isPrototypeOf
// Not that everything that inherits from Object.prototype will also inherit
// From Function.prototype
Function instanceof Object // of course true
```

Comment: Well, it makes any sense, but what about the `function Empty() {}`? EDIT: `Object.__proto__ == Function` will give you false. `Object.__proto__` refers directly to the `empty function` or via `Function.prototype`?

Comment: `Object.__proto__ == Function.prototype` just like `Car.__proto__==Function. prototype` in the example above.  Think about `a=new Object ()` or `a = new Function ()`, every constructor must be a function so it will inherit from `Function.prototype`

Comment: @Luis it refers directly to the empty function not "via `Function.prototype`. Both are independent references to the same `empty function` function object. If you reassign `Object.__proto__` it will not affect `Function.prototype` and vice versa. Mutation of course are visible for both since they reference the same object.

Comment: @Luis Is there something that's still not answered? `.prototype` only matters for `Constructor` functions when called with `new`. That creates a new object that extends the `Constructor.prototype`, and the `Constructor` can do some initialization of the newly created object. So that when you call new on the constructor, a new object is created using something like `Object.create(Constructor.prototype)`

Comment: That means when you create an object by using `new func()`, first it goes to func() (this is the constructor) and it returns an object + `__proto__` property which is the reference to func.prototype, right? just to be sure. In addition, `prototype` property is only inside `constructor functions` (or: inside any function, but just constructor functions really use it).

Comment: yes, `.prototype` is only used when `new MyFunc()` is called.