# Need direction for learning Object inheritance and code clean java script

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I am really fixed with JS object related concepts. For ex:
Crockford says:  Objects produced from object literals are linked to Object.prototype

Now on console when I type:

```
// input represented with >

> var a = {};
> console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(a));
Object {} // <-- output
> console.log(a.prototype);
undefined
```

Crockford says:Function objects are linked to Function.prototype (which is itself linked to Object.prototype)

```
> function b(){};
> console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(b));
function()
> console.log(b.prototype);
b{}
> console.log(b.prototype.prototype);
undefined
> console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(b.prototype));
Object {}
```

When I do getPrototypeOf() I get the expected output, but when I try to use the prototype property I get undefined. Cant figure out the reason.

Also for line 5 return value is function(). Can some please explain does this say ? I expected an Object to be returned.

It would be great if someone please give me insight/good links/some class diagrams(as we have in java) to follow for understanding prototypal inheritance.

Comment: Ordinary objects don't have a `prototype` property; that's why `Object.getPrototypeOf()` exists.

Comment: Also be aware that the browser console is not meant to be a vehicle for exploring JavaScript semantics; it's a tool meant to be useful to web developers for debugging etc. The console displays values in ways that are not always accurate with respect to language semantics.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy for the suggestion...can you suggest some links..I really wana fix this stuff once in for all (like u have things very crystal clear in java when coming to objects)...also adding to the response ....I am unable to access 'prototype' property but by using getPrototypeOf() I am able to get access of 'prototype' . Does that mean 'prototype' property is made private (may be by making use of closures) and is only accessible using a getter method

Comment: There is simply no "prototype" property on ordinary objects. Function objects have a "prototype" property, but not other objects. A search for "JavaScript inheritance tutorial" turns up **lots** of hits. Also the ["You Don't Know JS"](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS) series by my friend Kyle Simpson is available online and for purchase, and it includes coverage of inheritance.

Comment: The Prototype you are talking about is different from that of `prototype` property you are printing. Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9959753/1261124) great little answer, for a similar question!

Comment: objects to have a `__proto__` property, which is probably what you want. it's frowned upon to use though, but it's almost always the same as obj.constructor.prototype.

Comment: I suggest to check this link...absolutely wonderful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650764/how-does-proto-differ-from-constructor-prototype

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Here's the thing. There are some concepts in JS that seem really convoluted at the start, but are actually really straightforward. Let's have a look at a few of them.

#### 1) `function.prototype` property

When you define a function, the JS engine creates an anonymous object and binds the two using property names `prototype` and `constructor` as follows:

```
function foo(){}

/* Performed by JS engine internally */
// foo.prototype = {};
// foo.prototype.constructor = foo;
```

Therefore, only functions have `.prototype`.

The `.prototype` is used **only and only when** the function is invoked using the `new` operator.

#### 2) References

In JS, references can be used to pass along a variable, without creating a duplicate of it. Perhaps an example might help here:

```
var a = 1;

var b = { val: 1 };

var c = { val: 1 };

var x;

/*variable cloned*/
x = a;
x++;
console.log(a); // 1
console.log(x); // 2

/*variable refernced*/
x = b;
x.val++;
console.log(b); // { val: 2 }
console.log(x); // { val: 2 }

/*variable cloned*/
x = c.val;
x++;
console.log(c); // { val: 1 }
console.log(x); // 2
```

#### 3) `object.__proto__` property

Any object created by invoking a function with the `new` keyword, like `var x = new foo();`, will have a `__proto__` property on it that **is** the object **referenced** by its constructor function's `.prototype` property. Re-assigning `foo.prototype` to somethings else **will not** affect objects that have already been created.

In other words,

```
function foo(){}
// foo.prototype = {};
// foo.prototype.constructor = foo;

var x = new foo();

console.log(x.__proto__ === foo.prototype); // true
```

Also, when you create an object like `var x = {};`, it is the exact same thing as:

```
var x = new Object();
```

Therefore, `x.__proto__` **is** the object referenced by `Object.protoype`.

---

#### Conclusion

How does all this add up?

- `foo.prototype` acts as a "blueprint" for the objects created using the function `foo`.
- When we do create an object `x = new foo()`, JS engine stores a reference (link) to "the blueprint that was used to make `x`" as the `__proto__` property.

> When I do getPrototypeOf() I get the expected output, but when I try to use the prototype property I get undefined. Cant figure out the reason.

`Object.getPrototypeOf(...)` returns the `__proto__` property, not `prototype`.

> Also for line 5 return value is function(). Can some please explain does this say ? I expected an Object to be returned.

In JS, all data types have an associated "Wrapper" function.

Similar to how `x = {}` is the same as `x = new Object()`, doing `function b(){}` is the same as `b = new Function()`

since `b` was created invoking a function using `new`, it has a `__proto__` property, that **is** the object referenecd by its constructor function's prototype. In this case, `Function.prototype`, which is also Function.

---

Still confused? I'd recommend having a good long read at http://www.javascripttutorial.net/