# JavaScript - why doesn't setting prototypes prototype work?

Tags: javascript

I understand that inheritance in JavaScript can be accomplished with the following (copied from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)):

```
// Shape - superclass
function Shape() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
}

// superclass method
Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  this.x += x;
  this.y += y;
  console.info('Shape moved.');
};

// Rectangle - subclass
function Rectangle() {
  Shape.call(this); // call super constructor.
}

// subclass extends superclass
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;

var rect = new Rectangle();

console.log('Is rect an instance of Rectangle? ' + (rect instanceof Rectangle)); // true
console.log('Is rect an instance of Shape? ' + (rect instanceof Shape)); // true
rect.move(1, 1); // Outputs, 'Shape moved.'
```

What I'm not understanding is why replacing:

```
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;
```

with:

```
Rectangle.prototype.prototype = Shape.prototype;
```

doesn't accomplish the same thing?

Performing a similar manipulation on an instance seems to work fine.  Example:

```
var rect = new Rectangle();
rect.__proto__.__proto__ = Shape.prototype;
```

But manipulating prototypes this way is [discouraged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `inst.__proto__ == Rectangle.prototype`. If you wanted to manipulate the prototype (i.e. from what it inherits) of your `.prototype` object, you would have needed to use

```
Rectangle.prototype.__proto__ = Shape.prototype;
```

Comment: How are `Rectangle.prototype.__proto__` and `Rectangle.prototype.prototype` different?

Comment: One is *the* prototype, the other just a normal property that is used in the creation of instances with `new` and constructors. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/650764/1048572