# Why the prototype can be retrieved but the __proto__ is undefined in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, prototype, v8

Now I am learning JavaScript `prototype` and `__proto__`, and find several useful links

[__proto__ VS. prototype in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript)

[How does __proto__ differ from constructor.prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650764/how-does-proto-differ-from-constructor-prototype)

I can get the value of `__proto__` of object `f` in the following codes under Chrome.

```
var Foo = function() {}
var f = new Foo();
f.__proto__
> Foo {}
```

However, after setting the `Foo.prototype.__proto__` to `null`, the value of `__proto__` is `undefined`.

```
var Foo = function() {}
Foo.prototype = {name: 'cat', age: 10};
Foo.prototype.__proto__ = null;
var f = new Foo();
f.__proto__
> undefined
```

But I can get the value of `f.name`, which is `cat`. Here is my understanding, since the value `f.name` can be retrievable, the `__proto__` of object `f` should point to `Foo.prototype`. Why the value of `f.__proto__` is `undefined`?

Comment: I think this is actually a *decent* question, even if the behavior (when investigated) happens to be browser-specific. *There is a very specific case/context asked about, which seems counter to face-value expectations*. `__proto__` has been long-supported in Chrome and Firefox (and WebKit?) and *is* standardized in ES6. Since this is *now semi-defacto behavior* (and upcoming supported behavior) and the *specific context is discussed* an "answer" of "should not use" is not really an answer, even if such a statement may make a good closing summary.

Comment: I've opened a bug for this behavior: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=506166

Comment: I answered this question incorrectly in July. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: @apsillers, why the newest question could be duplicated as my question, IMO, my question is earlier than the duplicated one. please correct me, if I missing something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the ES2015 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.prototype.__proto__), `__proto__` is an accessor property that is **inherited from `Object.prototype`**.

Since your prototype chain for the instance `f` is rooted in `null`, rather than `Object.prototype`, the `f` object does not inherit any properties from `Object.prototype`, including `Object.prototype.__proto__`.

The object still knows its prototype internally (through [[Prototype]] internal slot), but it does not inherit the `__proto__` accessor property for getting this value. You can still access it through `Object.getPrototypeOf(f)`, though.

See also the resolution on the Chromium issue "[`obj.__proto__` is undefined if prototype chain does not contain `Object.prototype`](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=506166)":

> This is working as specified. ES6 __proto__ is a getter defined on Object.prototype. For an object that doesn't have that in its prototype chain it is not accessible (just like, say, hasOwnProperty isn't). You need to use Object.getPrototypeOf instead.

Answer (score 5):

`__proto__` is an internal special property of JavaScript. you should not use.

From [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)

> While Object.prototype.**proto** is supported today in most browsers, its existence and exact behavior has only been standardized in the ECMAScript 6 specification as a legacy feature to ensure compatibility for web browsers. For better support, it is recommended that only Object.getPrototypeOf() be used instead.

Comment: `__proto__` - at least the access of - is in ECMA 6th edition and *is* supported in Chrome in this manner, see [MDN's entry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto). Anyway this "answer" does not address the question asked. Use a comment for a .. comment.

Comment: It does answer _"Why the value of `f.__proto__` is `undefined`?"_

Comment: `__proto__` is neither internal nor special.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question; this answer is answering the question "Should I use `__proto__`?" which not being asked here. This might possibly be okay as a comment. If I ask on Biology.SE, "What is the chemical composition that makes nightshade plants so poisonous?" then it does not answer my question to tell me, "Nightshade plants are often lethally poisonous; you should not eat them."