# Inheritance of FUNCTIONS is becoming a nightmare

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, inheritance, prototype

I was going through the concept of inheritance ,Now the situation is that let us have and empty constructor function

```
function Constructor(/* i am an empty function  */ );
```

Now we are going to add a property to Object.prototype and make an instance of Constructor function

```
Object.prototype.game = "hello i am a game";
 let a =  new Constructor();
 a.game();
```

Now we Know the output is Going to be ***"hello i am a game"***.Therefore ***var a inherits from Object*** and ***therefore Constructor function inherits from Object*** therefore

```
Constructor.__proto__ === Object.prototype
```

Must be **true** than why is it coming out to be **false**

Comment: `__proto__` and `prototype` both are objects. So you cannot use `===` on them

Comment: Your example code does not work (`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;` and `Uncaught TypeError: a.game is not a function`), so what exactly are you even asking about?

Comment: "inherits from" is not the same as "directly inherits from". So instead of testing `Object.getPrototypeOf(a) == b` (btw, do not use the deprecated `__proto__`!), you would need to do `b.isPrototypeOf(a)` which traverses the whole chain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Constructor.**proto** === Object.prototype

No that should not be true. What should be true is as follows:

```
a.__proto__ === Constructor.prototype
```

However (in this case)

```
Constructor.prototype.__proto__ === Object.prototype
```

should be true.

---

First one directly follows from prototype definition.
`__proto__` property of an object created from a constructor function is equal to `prototype` of that function.

Second one follows from fact that `Constructor.prototype` is also an object - and was created using `Object` constructor function (hence similar to first case its `__proto__` must be equal to `prototype` of constructor function, which is `Object.prototype`).

PS. But to directly answer your question to what `Constructor.__proto__` equals, it is `Function.prototype` (reasoning could go like: this is because `Function` object was the one who created your `Constructor` function).

Comment: ya thats working but can you please give a little bit explanation about it that why this going to be true

Comment: Thank you very much @GiorgiMoniava Now i got to know where i was going wrong

Comment: @HARSHBAJPAI you can mark answer as accepted if that's the case ;) further reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650764/how-does-proto-differ-from-constructor-prototype

Comment: i will accept your answer but it will take 4 minutes to do so as you can't accept an answer before 4 minutes