# Why is it bad to add properties to prototype of object with __proto__ compared to 'prototype'?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
function Person(name, age, height) {
    this.name = name,
    this.age = age,
    this.height = height
}

var john = new Person("John", 24, 175);
```

What I read should be avoided:

```
john.__proto__.fact = "I am a humanly human!"
```

What should be done instead:

```
Person.prototype.fact = "I am a humanly human!"
```

Comment: Why do you want to do **either**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does \_\_proto\_\_ differ from constructor.prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650764/how-does-proto-differ-from-constructor-prototype)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder read my mind.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder To add methods such that they are not present in every Person object you create.

Comment: @Ch3wbacc4: Adding to `john.__proto__` will add methods to every `Person` object, if `john`'s prototype is the same object as `Person.prototype` (e.g., in your example).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add to the prototype of the object `john` refers to, doing so through `john.__proto__` gives the impression to the reader of the code that this change is specific to `john` somehow, which it isn't; it affects **all** objects that use that prototype (current and future). Using `Person.prototype` doesn't give that impression, it correctly indicates what you're doing.

Separately, note that not all objects (not even all objects with prototypes) have `__proto__`, because `__proto__` is inherited from `Object.prototype`, but not all objects inherit from `Object.prototype`. For that reason, in new code, it's best to avoid `__proto__` entirely; use `Object.getPrototypeOf` instead if you need to get the prototype of an object: `Object.getPrototypeOf(john)`.

In a comment you've answered the question of why you'd want to do this with:

> To add methods such that they are not present in every Person object you create.

...but that's exactly what adding to `john.__proto__` would do: Add the method to every `Person` object (indirectly through the prototype), current and future, exactly like adding to `Person.prototype` — because those (and `Object.getPrototypeOf(john)`) are all just different ways of getting to the *same* object:

```js
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
var john = new Person("John");
console.log(john.__proto__ === Person.prototype);              // true
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(john) === Person.prototype); // true

var paul = new Person("Paul");

john.__proto__.someNewMethod = function() {
  console.log(this.name);
};

john.someNewMethod(); // "John"
paul.someNewMethod(); // "Paul"
```

If you want to add a method just to the object `john` refers to, don't use `__proto__` or `Person.prototype` at all: Just do:

```
john.niftyMethod = function() { /*....*/ };
```