# What is meaning of Function.prototype.__proto__?

Tags: javascript, function, object, prototype

I am a beginner in `Javascript` and am learning about `Object Oriented` and `prototyping` in it.

As far as I know, `Object` is a function and is created by Function because `Object.__proto__ === Function.prototype` but looking through various diagrams online, I am quite confused by fact that How `Function.prototype.__proto__ === Object.prototype`.

What does `Function.prototype.__proto__` mean?

Isn't it something that is developed by language owners as Function is the first thing from which everything arrives.

Then what does it mean? Am I lacking some important fact? I looked through other **StackOverflow** answers but can't find anything related to it.

Comment: It could be useful: https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-s-the-difference-between-class-prototypal-inheritance-e4cd0a7562e9

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does \_\_proto\_\_ differ from constructor.prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650764/how-does-proto-differ-from-constructor-prototype)

Comment: __proto__ always refers to the supertype of the object so in our case if it is suffixed to Function.prototype will be similar to Object.prototype because Object being the supertype of function

Comment: @BenFortune please understand my question. My doubt arised by looking diagram of question that you have posted. How is it duplicate of it?

Comment: `__proto__` is a deprecated way to access object prototype (not prototype property but  internal `[[Prototype]]` slot). Modern way would be `Reflect.getPropotypeOf`. `Function.prototype` is  instance of `Object` and inherits from `Object.prototype`. So everything you add   `Object.prototype.test = 'test'; console.log((function(){}).test)` would be inherited.

Comment: Thank you @YuryTarabanko. If Function.prototype is instance of Object then why Object.__proto__ === Function.prototype. It means that Object is instance of Function?

Comment: @SEN Have you noticed that Function.__proto__ === Object.__proto__ is also true.

Comment: Yes `Object` is a function. Notice capital letter. `typeof  Object === 'function'`. Everything you add to `Function.prototype` would be inherited by every function. `Function.prototype.test = 'test'; console.log(Object.test)`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Object is instance of Function and Function.prototype is instance of Object. Isn't it creating cycle(depend on each other)? Who came early?

Comment: @RK_15 yes. I have noticed. Does that mean that they have some other common parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TL;DR

`__proto__` is a property of an `object` which enables you to look up in the prototype chain. While `prototype` is a property of a `Function` which enables you to add shareable functionalities to a constructor function.

> Long Answer

Understand this from an example, let's say you create a constructor function.

`function A() {}` and then create an instance of it, `var a = new A()`.

Then, add a function as following:

`A.prototype.getA = function () { return 'A'; }`.

Now, if you try to access `a.getA()`, you'll get the result, i.e. `getA` will be executed.

But how does it know about the function `getA` even though `getA` has been added after the instance `a` was created. It's because of using `__proto__`, you can traverse up in the chain (you must have heard about prototype chaining).

Technically, `__proto__` is a property of an object, while `prototype` is a property of `function`. But how could `functions` have property? Because everything in JavaScript is converted implicitly to an object. Ever wondered how could you something like this: `'test'.toUpperCase()`? Isn't string literals are 'not object' and they are primitives?

Read this for reference: http://jayendra.co.in/objects-in-javascript/

Now to answer your question:

> What does `Function.prototype.__proto__` mean?

You are trying to access the `prototype` property of `Function` constructor function. Remember, `prototype` itself is an `object`, so you can access properties like `constructor` and `__proto__`.

> `Function.prototype.__proto__ === Object.prototype`

To enable chaining, when you access `__proto__` property, you are looking up!

> Any function can access all the properties of an object. How?

A property of `Object`, let's say `toString`. You can do, `A.toString() // A created at the start`. But we never created a function `toString` for `A` constructor function!

Answer (score 1):

`myFunc.prototype` is the `__proto__` of any object constructed by calling `new myFunc()`.

Thinking in terms of classical (Java- or C++-style) OO, you could say that `myFunc` is a constructor and (therefore) `myFunc.prototype` is the class. In that sense, `myFunc.prototype.__proto__` is the superclass; that is, the prototype of the prototype of all objects created with `new myFunc`.

One useful thing you can do to `myFunc.prototype.__proto__` is assign to it to create a superclass relationship, e.g.

```
myFunc.prototype.__proto__ = mySuperclassConstructor.prototype
```

This idiom sheds light on why `Function.prototype.__proto__ === Object.prototype`  holds (the core of your question): it simply means that `Function` is a subclass of `Object` — Or in other words, JavaScript runtimes do something equivalent to the above code snippet in their prelude so as to make `Function` a subclass of `Object` (as they should, per [ECMA-262](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) §§ 19.2.2 and 19.2.3)

Careful though, while `__proto__` [happens to work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto#Browser_compatibility) on all modern (2019) JavaScript implementations (node.js and browsers), its use is [both non-standard and slow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto). [Consider using “real” ES6 classes instead.](https://medium.com/beginners-guide-to-mobile-web-development/super-and-extends-in-javascript-es6-understanding-the-tough-parts-6120372d3420)